# Array looping and comparing if >2 differences

Tags: c#, arraylist, hashset

I'm trying to check the difference between a master list of items in c# vs an array of lists.

Not quite sure how to build this logic in an efficient way.

Example:

My master list of items is: `var MasterOrderIDs = {1,2,3,4}`

Then I have an Customer/Order object where it's storing the Customer ID along with its OrderID

```
CustomerID|OrderID
    1     |  1
    1     |  2
    1     |  3
    1     |  4
    1     |  5
    2     |  1
    2     |  2
    2     |  3
    2     |  4
    2     |  5
    2     |  6
    3     |  2
    3     |  3
    3     |  4
```

I want to return an array which has the CustomerID along with the OrderIDs where the difference of the MasterOrderIDs has a difference of less than 2.

Something like:
`var OrderDifferences = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();`

So in the case of the Customer/Order, I want to return:

`{[1, [5]], [3, [1]}`

This is because for CustomerID 1, there is a Order ID 5, which is less than 2 differences. Likewise with CustomerID 3, there is a Order ID 1, which appears in MasterOrderIDs and is less than 2 differences.

How can I create such a check?

Ina real-life scenario I will have big data so wondering what would be the best efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Just to make it clear - what exactly do you mean by **changes**?

Comment: I mean Differences. So MasterOrderIDs = {1,2,3,4} is the set I want to check for each Customer ID and its Orders. So CustomerID 1 has OrderIDs of {1,2,3,4,5}. There is a difference of 1 because the OrderID '5'.

Comment: One more question. What is the expected number of records that you are going to work with? I can think of some small optimizations but for something really perforement maybe someone else would need to answer.

Comment: Customer/Order will have say 300000 records.

Comment: It will be time/resource consuming to do this in memory. TBH I would try to think for some solution that will perform the heavy lifting on the database server but anyways I will post an answer within few minutes so you can use it as a starting point if you decide to do this on the server side.

Comment: Appreciate it. We are looking at doing this in memory vs database. Since we can easily scale the server and it's more difficult with a Database.

Comment: Hmm, something else. For `CustomerId = 2` you also have difference of 1. Only `OrderId = 6`. Does it mean that if a customer has an order with OrderId which is not in the MasterOrderIds List you automatically discard this Customer and all his orders?

Comment: Well in the case of `CustomerId = 2`, there is a difference of 2 because of `OrderId = 5` and `OrderId = 6`. We discard it and don't need it in the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information that we got I can think of two relatively small optimizations. So my disclaimer is that the basic approach is still brute force and maybe there is a smarter way to extract the information but we can still perform some checks in order to exclude some of the uneccessary data.

**Small optimization 1**

We are looking for Customers who compared to the the master list of orders have one more or one less order at most. In other words, based on your example for

`var MasterOrderIDs = {1,2,3,4}`

a Customer with 5 orders like `customerOrders = { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 }` is still potentially valid but customer with 6 orders `customerOrders = { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }` is not.

The same for the bottom number. A Customer with 3 orders is also potentially valid `customerOrders = { 7, 8, 9 }` but a customer with less the two orders `customerOrders = { 7, 8 }` is not.

So based on this we can perform our first small optimization filering customers who have more than `MasterOrderIDs.Count() + 2` orders or with less than `MasterOrderIDs.Count() - 2`

**Small optimization 2**

Even if we are in the appropriate range of orders we want to make sure that our orderIds overlap. We can allow only 1 order which is present in one of the lists and not present in the other. Basically this is not exactly an optimization, but this is second criteria based on which we can construct our query.

Which is:

First seed some data:

```
class Order
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public static List<Order> Seed()
    {
        return new List<Order>
        {
            new Order { CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 1},
            new Order { CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 2},
            new Order { CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 3},
            new Order { CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 4},
            new Order { CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 5},
            new Order { CustomerId = 2, OrderId = 1},
            new Order { CustomerId = 2, OrderId = 2},
            new Order { CustomerId = 2, OrderId = 3},
            new Order { CustomerId = 2, OrderId = 4},
            new Order { CustomerId = 2, OrderId = 5},
            new Order { CustomerId = 2, OrderId = 6},
            new Order { CustomerId = 3, OrderId = 2},
            new Order { CustomerId = 3, OrderId = 3},
            new Order { CustomerId = 3, OrderId = 4}
        };
    }
}
```

Then set the initial data:

```
var masterList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var upperBorder = masterList.Count() + 2;
var bottomBorder = masterList.Count() - 2;
var orders = Order.Seed();
```

And finally extract the records that we need:

```
var ordersWithinRange = orders
                .GroupBy(o => o.CustomerId)
                .Where(x => x.Count() < upperBorder && x.Count() > bottomBorder && x.Select(o => o.OrderId).Except(masterList).Concat(masterList.Except(x.Select(o => o.OrderId))).Count() < 2)
                .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Select(o => o.OrderId).Except(masterList).Concat(masterList.Except(d.Select(o => o.OrderId))).ToList());
```

Again. This will take a lot of computing time but I think it's a little bit faster than a sequence of for loops filtering one thing at a time.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding this bit:


`x.Select(o => o.CensusId).Except(masterList).Concat(masterList.Except(x.Select(o => o.CensusId))).Count()`

Comment: @IntermediaryDeveloper The idea is that we don't know which `List<int>` contains unique ID. When we say `Select(o => o.CensusId).Except(masterList)` we return those Ids which are projected from the `Select` but now within `masterList`. However the case may be that the `masterList` has a unique Id. Thus we perform perform the same `Except` operation for boths lists getting the unique values from each of them and then `Concat` them in one `List<int>`. You can google `C# find unique values for two lists` for more detailed information.